# Hallucinating + [preposition]

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I’m trying to decide which preposition to use to complete a statement about Charlotte Perkins Gillman’s short story “The Yellow Wallpaper”. I am describing how a hysterical woman sees things in her wallpaper. Over time these things become the image of a woman. To introduce the situation, I have written the following:

> She was hallucinating [*preposition*] the wallpaper.

*[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hallucinate?q=hallucinate)* gives a usage example wherein *hallucinate* is used transitively with no preposition:

> I don’t care if they’re hallucinating purple snakes.

This to me sounds like people are seeing purple snakes that are not there. I'm looking for the best way to say that a woman is looking at real wallpaper and seeing it move.

An [ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hallucinating%20about%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) search produces a lot of hits for `hallucinate about`, but those also largely represent that a person sees something that isn’t present. For [example](http://books.google.es/books?id=qM2UvPbBHN4C&pg=PA45&dq=%22hallucinating%20about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Wrj6UP6EGc2JhQeomID4DA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hallucinating%20about%22&f=false),

> His last days were spent strapped down in a hospital bed *hallucinating about* snakes and people who wanted to hurt him. [*emphasis added*]

Is there a correct preposition to use with *hallucinate* to mean that a person sees something unreal happening inside something real? Or is this improper usage of the word?

Two prepositions I considered are:

- hallucinate *over* (similar to *suffer anxiety over*)
- hallucinate *on* (similar to *trippin’ on*)

Comment: There's the well-known expression 'cracking over the wallpaper', of course.

Comment: I've never heard it. "Crack" as in "break down"?

Comment: http://www.thefix.com/content/drinking-license-uk-booze9779 may contain a more well-known expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly can follow *hallucinating* with a preposition, but I don't think any well describes the relationship between the hallucinations and the wallpaper in that story.

> She was hallucinating a woman in the wallpaper.
>
> She was having hallucinations, projected on to the wallpaper.
>
> The wallpaper became the focus of her hallucinations.

I would all be happy with.

> She saw hallucinations in the wallpaper.

I would also be happy with.

I'm inclined to the first, but that's partly because I think the fact that the hallucination was of a woman is itself significant in my reading of that story. You may disagree, or it may be irrelevant to your piece.

Comment: Eventually she sees a woman in the wallpaper, and I would say that she *hallucinates a woman in the wallpaper* then, but early on she doesn't see anything in particular. I want to introduce that she is seeing things in the wallpaper, things that will eventually form into something  clear.

Comment: True, it's a while since I've read it. Any of the above, or also "The wallpaper became the focus of hallucinations", (dropping the *her*) might be more appropriate to introducing the hallucinations. On the other hand, it's not clear at that point that we are reading a psychological horror, so the reader may suspect that there is indeed something strange about the wallpaper and the story is a supernatural horror. Again though, that could be completely irrelevant to what your piece.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to say:

> ***"She hallucinated moving images in the patterns or designs of the wallpaper."***

OR

> ***"She hallucinated snakes and other moving images in the wallpaper's pattern or design."***

Comment: Or just "hallucinated movement in the wallpaper."